# Ionic, "cordova" not included in platforms, native plugins not working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have inherited an Ionic 5 project with Angular and Cordova - not Capacitor. It is using a couple of native plugins, namely QR Scanner and In-app Browser. The application works fine when launching in the Android emulator using:

```sh
ionic cordova run android
```

Now I want to build an APK that I can distribute to a few testers to give the application a try. This APK has to be built using a specific configuration to connect to a pre-production environment (using Firebase, but that shouldn't matter I guess). The process I am using is:

```sh
ionic build --prod --platform=android --configuration=preprod
ionic cordova prepare android --no-build --prod
ionic cordova build android --no-build --release
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <PATH_TO_KS> <PATH_TO_APK> <KEY_NAME>
zipalign -v 4 <PATH_TO_APK> <PATH_TO_SIGNED_APK>
```

Now the signed APK installs correctly to the emulator and the application starts AND connects to the pre-production environment. **But the native plugins (e.g. QR Scanner) do not work.** The **error** I am getting is **Native: tried calling QRScanner.prepare, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator**. It seems that Cordova is not active because when printing the platforms, they do not include the `"cordova"` string:

```js
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(private platform: Platform) {...}

ngOnInit() {
  this.platforms = this.platform.platforms().join(',');
}
```

The result of `this.platforms` is **android,phablet,cordova,desktop,hybrid** when running with `ionic cordova run android`, but is just **android,phablet,desktop** when installing the APK I built with the process above.

Do you have any ideas why? I am quite new to mobile development, so you can absolutely assume I have made newbie mistakes. And if you feel that any other information would be useful, please let me know and I will happily  add it.

---

**EDIT:** In order to support the `preprod` configuration, I added the following sections in angular.json:

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "preprod": {
              ...
}}}}}}}
```

Building with just `ionic cordova build android` yields the following error:

```
> ng run app:ionic-cordova-build:preprod --platform=android
An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'preprod' is not set in the workspace.
```

This is why I am building in 3 phases, `ionic build ...  --configuration=preprod`, `ionic cordova prepare ...`, `ionic cordova build android --no-build`. My intention is for the first to build the app in the correct configuration, the second to update the Android project with the web files built with the configuration and the third to build the final APK.

Comment: Why do you need to give the testers a signed apk? It can be a debug one. Signing is only required if you want to send the app to the store.

Comment: Hi Dimitri, thanks for your comment. I will need to sign the APK eventually to publish it, so I *guess* there is no harm in doing it for the preview version. Do you think that signing interferes with the operation of Cordova?

Comment: The google store has moved away from APKs for new apps and is now only accepting AAB (Android bundles). You might want to have a read here https://ionicframework.com/blog/google-play-android-app-bundle-requirement-for-new-apps/

Comment: Also when you say the plugins do not work, what errors are you getting exactly? For QRScanner for instance, have you tried calling it and what error do yo get?

Comment: Hi Dimitri, I will take a look into the AAB. I added the error message in the question, "Native: tried calling QRScanner.prepare, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator".

Comment: Also try building the apk with just a single command "ionic cordova build android"

Comment: Hi Dimitri, yes this was the pointer to the right direction. I added an explanation of why I am using 3 steps for the build and what happens when I build with just `ionic cordova build android`. This led me to add the following configuration to angular.json, which makes `ionic cordova build android --configuration=preprod` work: added `projects.app.architect.ionic-cordova-build.configurations.preprod = { "browserTarget": "app:build:preprod" }`. Please add an answer with this and I will accept it. It would be great if you could optionally explain what is wrong with the 3 steps build. Thank you!

Comment: I still don't understand why you need to complicate the build so much. 'ionic cordova build android' should be making debug (preproduction) apks and the same with '--release' should be making the .aab that is required for the store. Unless you have specific environment changes that are needed in your custom 'preprod' configuration. It's not one of the default configurations. Glad you got it sorted though!

Comment: Yes, I need a custom configuration (or so I believe) to target the staging environment of Firebase. This is the reason for the `--configuration` switch and relevant changes.

Comment: Fair enough. You know the exact requirements better. However, please keep in mind that a system like that exists by default. Have a look in `src/environments`. The normal one will be used by default and the .prod.ts one for when you use --prod on the single build command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242479/discussion-between-dimitrios-matanis-and-nikos-paraskevopoulos).

Comment: Indeed, I needed a third, that is why I got into all the trouble: so, 1 config is for local deployment (Firebase emulator), 1 for production (real data, *danger*), 1 for preproduction (call it staging, QA, whatever, dummy data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple normal way of building a new app for debug (apk) is just calling

```
ionic cordova build android
```

This calls prepare internally, so no need for another call. It will produce an apk file that you can use for testing on devices (and possibly emulators depending on functionality).

When it's time to release to the store, considering this is a new app and Google's requirements have changed, you need to build a `.aab` file. The following will do that:

```
ionic cordova build android --release
```

As for signing, you need to provide the key to Google and they will sign it for you via the .aab provided. This is explained in more detail here:

https://ionicframework.com/blog/google-play-android-app-bundle-requirement-for-new-apps/

Now, if you need to create a custom configuration (what you're referring as `preprod`) because you have some very specific *angular* environment changes or requirements, outside of what the defaults have to offer, as you found out in the comments, you will need to edit the `angular.json` file to add it.

Ionic by default provides a structure for environment variables, which can be found in `src/environments`. More details about how this works can be found here:

https://medium.com/swlh/environment-variables-in-angular-ionic-8aa1698f2cc5